# Mono equiv to windows services hosting

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, hosting, wcf

Does anyone know, with good experience of mono development, what the equiv, if any, on Mono, of hosting in a windows service. I see you can host, XPS, Mod_mono on Apache, and half a dozen other web server extensions, and of course via ServiceHost. I don't think their needs to be since you can use ServiceHost to create a console program and get it started via rc.d.

Thanks.
Bob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit from the the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase class to implement your own daemon service controlled by monod daemon.

Hope that helps.
 Bob.